# Stop Regex Engine at first match

Tags: regex, performance, pcre

Given this regular expression:

```
^.*?f
```

on this test string:

```
abcdefgh
ijklm
noprcbm
abcdefgh
ijklm
noprcbm
abcdefgh
ijkl ... very loooooong string
```

as in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sm9H1n/1)

I noticed that it takes more time for the match to be returned, the longer the string.
Even though the expression is asking to match the very first occurrance and nothing else.

Is there a way to write the expression in a way, so the engine will stop and return the match as soon as it finds it, disregarding the length of the string?

Comment: Could you enlighten us, **where** in the regex syntax presented here, you have found any such property of telling us, the compiled process to find ***( only )* The First Occurrence** of the "*any-such-to-be-matched* **string** ? Thank you.

Comment: I am not well enough versed in regular expressions to answer your question. From your comments, it looks like, the instruction to find ( only ) The First Ocurrence, is not there. Even thoguh this is what it is matching, which is what I am looking for. Therefore my question, what do I need to add or modify in the regex syntax, to tell the compiled process to find ( only ) The First Ocurrence of the "any-such-to-be-matched string ?

Comment: Do you mean using a negated character class? `^[^f]*f` https://regex101.com/r/N5dQPm/1

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird I tested your expression and there was no performance improvement. Basically, it takes the software I am using, 1sec to match the first `abcdef` in 450Mb worth of data, and it takes ~0ms when the data is 1kb. So my question is, how to get the match out of the 450Mb in ~0ms, since the match is in the first line, same as in the 1kb?